# How can I speed up flatten?

Tags: scala

I have this method:

```
val reportsWithCalculatedUsage = time("Calculate USAGE") {
  reportsHavingCalculatedCounter.flatten.flatten.toList.groupBy(_._2.product).mapValues(_.map(_._2)) mapValues { list =>
    list.foldLeft(List[ReportDataHelper]()) {
      case (Nil, head) =>
        List(head)
      case (tail, head) =>
        val previous = tail.head
        val current = head copy (
          usage = if (head.machine == previous.machine) head.counter - previous.counter else head.usage)
        current :: tail
    } reverse
  }
}
```

Where `reportsHavingCalculatedCounter` is of type: `val reportsHavingCalculatedCounter: 
 scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Strin
 g,com.agilexs.machinexs.logic.ReportDataHelper]]]`.

This code works perfectly. The problem is that this `reportsHavingCalculatedCounter` has maps inside it whom sum of `ReportDataHelper` objects (map values) is about 50 000 entries and the `flatten.flatten` takes about 15s to be processed.

I've also tried with 2 flat maps but that's almost the same (time consuming). Is there any way to improve this? (please ignore `foldLeft` or `reverse`; if I remove that the issue is still present, the most time consuming are those 2 `flatten`).

**UPDATE**: I've tried with a different scenario:

```
val reportsHavingCalculatedCounter2: Seq[ReportDataHelper] = time("Counter2") {
  val builder = new ArrayBuffer[ReportDataHelper](50000)
  var c = 0
  reportsHavingCalculatedCounter.foreach { v =>
    v.foreach { v =>
      v.values.foreach { v =>
        c += 1
        builder += v
      }
    }
  }
  println("Count:" + c)
  builder.result
}
```

And it takes: `Counter2 (15.075s)`.

I can't imagine that scala is slow. This is the slowest part `v.values.foreach`.

Comment: I think this question is better placed at [CodeReview](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: To make it faster check out the `.par` element of collections, more info can be found here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Comment: You have O(N*N*N*eC) complexity, maybe you should redesign algorithm? For example calculate usage on writies.

Comment: @EECOLOR Thanks for that, I've used `.par` and it now takes half of initial time.